# Grammar dictionary

Tags: grammar, dictionary

The dictionary that I use primarily is http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/ . I wanted to know of good sources online for looking up how different aspects of Japanese grammar work. I would prefer it if the site were completely in Japanese. I understand Japanese well enough that I should be able to figure out what is being said if the explanations are in Japanese. At this point for me I feel it is a waste of study time to look up Japanese words in English, which is why I use http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/ . I would like to do the same thing when studying grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We generally do not deal with [resource questions](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/what-questions-are-not-allowed-on-japanese-language-and-usage/797#797) on JLU.

These sorts of questions are relatively common, though, and to provide a starting point, a number of us have created a [resource list](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756) on the meta site as a part of this site's FAQ.

In this particular case, you will find a few sites like what you're looking for in the Japanese section of the [Websites](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese/767#767) section.

For questions like this, as well as the other types of questions considered [offtopic](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796), feel free to drop by the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/511/japanese-language-and-usage), although you may need to link your account to another stackexchange site to get enough rep to chat freely.